# How to power third pin "neon lamp" on thermal breaker switch C1005B?

Tags: switches, circuit-breaker

I'm using a C1005B 10A illuminated breaker switch to toggle 120VAC by breaking the hot wire. The switch has three pins

1. Neon lamp
2. Load
3. SW line

Should pin 1 be attached to the  load or SW line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the neon lamp is to light when the switch is ON, pin 1 should be connected to Neutral.

If the neon lamp is to light when the switch is OFF (so you can find the switch in the dark), pin 1 should be connected to the SW Line terminal.

This assumes the other terminal of the neon lamp is connected internally to the Load terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the schematic.

[image]

The pin configuration has been extracted from page 2 of the data sheet , courtesy of [Mouser](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/240/C1005B_from_Thermal_Catalog-3050230.pdf).

Please refer 'Dimensional Specs'.

[image]

The neon will light up indicating that the circuit breaker has been closed to energise the load.